# Reduce omp critical section to compare_exchange_weak in BFS

Tags: c++, openmp, compare-and-swap

I have this working implementation of BFS.

```cpp
std::unordered_map<decltype(root->id()), std::atomic<bool>> visited;

#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for ...

        #pragma omp critical
        {
            if (visited.find(next->id()) == visited.end()) {
                next_frontier.push_back(next);
                visited.emplace(next->id(), true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I somehow reduce that critical section to `compare_exchange_weak`?

I've tried

```cpp
bool expected = false;
if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&visited[next->id()], &expected, true)) {
    #pragma omp critical
    next_frontier.push_back(next);
}
```

But I get:

- malloc(): unsorted double linked list corrupted
- double free or corruption (out)
- Segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

None of the standard C++ containers are thread-safe for modification. That includes `unordered_map` and whatever `next_frontier` is in your code (I assume a vector?).

It seems like `unordered_map` is overkill anyway because you just need to note that a node has been visited. That's what `unordered_set` is for.

Now for your purpose you would need a lock-free hash table to replace that unordered set.

If you know that your node IDs are reasonably compact integers, e.g. small unsigned integers, you can instead use an atomic bit map. This should work:

```
const unsigned max_id = ...;
std::unique_ptr<std::atomic<std::uint32_t>[]> visited(
    new std::atomic<std::uint32_t>[(max_id + 32) / 32]);
#pragma omp parallel
{
    unsigned id = ...;
    unsigned index = id / 32;
    unsigned bit = id % 32;
    unsigned mask = 1 << bit;
    if(! (visited[index].fetch_or(mask, std::memory_order_relaxed) & mask)) {
        // new node
    }
}
```

In the absence of a better solution you can at least make your critical section shorter and split it in two.

```
std::unordered_set<decltype(root->id())> visited;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    auto id = next->id();
    bool newnode;
#   pragma omp critical
    newnode = visited.emplace(id).second;
    if(newnode) {
#       pragma omp critical
        next_frontier.push_back(next);
    }
}
```

You can also split the load with some hashing. The idea is to scatter the visited-set across multiple sets so that the chance of two threads accessing the same map is lower.

```
template<class T>
struct Bin
{
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unordered_set<T> entries;
};
template<class T>
struct PaddedBin: Bin<T>
{
# ifdef __cpp_lib_hardware_interference_size
    static constexpr std::size_t cacheline_size =
        std::hardware_destructive_interference_size;
# else
    static constexpr std::size_t cacheline_size = 64;
# endif
    char padding[(sizeof(Bin<T>) + cacheline_size - 1) & -cacheline_size];
};
void bfs()
{
    using key_type = decltype(root->id());
    std::array<PaddedBin<key_type>, 61 /*low prime number*/> visited;
#   pragma omp parallel
    {
        key_type id = next->id();
        std::size_t hash = std::hash<key_type>{}(id);
        Bin& bin = visited[hash % visited.size()];
        bool newnode;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(bin.mutex);
            newnode = bin.entries.emplace(id).second;
        }
        if(newnode) {
#           pragma omp critical
            frontier.push_back(next);
        }
    }
}
```